# How display "Only X left Threshold" when "Allow Qty Below 0 and Notify Customer" is selected?

Tags: magento2.3

"Only X left Threshold" is display only if "No Backorders" is selected.

[image: Only X left Threshold]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I experienced the same bug issue using Magento 2.3.5-p1 (also 2.3.4) when trying to display "Display Products Availability in Stock on Storefront" and setting "Out-of-Stock Threshold" to 0.

An imperfect alternative is to set the "Out-of-Stock Threshold" value to -1.
However, this method will inflate the "Availability: In Stock Only xx left" by a quantity of +1. Certainly, not an accurate available quantity.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this package to just show qty https://www.metagento.com/blog/magento-2-show-stock-quantity

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/196565)